# Correctly mutating state in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming, state

I want to organize my program around immutable state (using case class) and a chain of functions that update it.

```
case class State(conn: Connection, file: FileInputStream, data: Data)
```

First two functions in that chain just open the connection and the input stream and the rest use these resources. So these are my options as I see them:

1. Using nulls when initializing state:

```
    State(conn = null, file = null, data = new Data())
    .pipe(getConnection)
    .pipe(openStream)
    .pipe(processData)
    .pipe(doCleanUp)
```

Where the state gets updated in functions like that:

```
  val newConn = ???
  st.copy(conn = newConn)
```

This way the code remain relatively clean, but if the order of functions gets changed in the future, I will face the dreaded NullPointerException.

2. Declaring conn and file as Options and wrapping State in Either.

```
    case class State(conn: Option[Connection], file: Option[FileInputStream], data: Data)
    Right(State(conn = null, file = null, data = new Data()))
    .pipe(...
```

In doing that the problem with nulls gets elegantly solved, but all the functions that deal with data have to implement a large portion of boilerplate code in order to unwrap the options.

```
  {
    case Left(ex) => Left(ex)
    case Right(st) if st.conn.isEmpty => Left(new Exception("Connection is missing"))
    case Right(st) if st.file.isEmpty => Left(new Exception("File stream is missing"))
    case Right(st) =>
      ...
  }
```

The resulting code is more robust and functional but this kind of boilerplate in every function is a bit bothersome. Is there a more idiomatic and nimble approach to this problem?

Comment: An input stream is mutable so you are not wining something with wrapping it on a case class. If you want to follow this style correctly I would recommend you to take a look to streaming implementations like **fs2**, **AkkaStreams**, **Monix**, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I think, you are overthinking it ... it's not a state, really, just a couple of parameters (a state is something that gets mutated during the process, it is not the case here).

Why not just make parameters explicit:

```
def openConnection(): Connection = ??? 
def openStream(c: Connection): InputStream = ??? 
def processData(stream: InputStream, data: Data): Unit = ??? 
def cleanup(c: Connection): Unit
```

This way, you don't need ugly nulls, and there is no way someone can call these
functions incorrectly or in a wrong order by mistake.

You can make it look nicer/fancier if you wrap the return values into some monad (an `Option` or a `Future` perhaps, or, maybe `Try` or `Either` for error handling):

```
def openConnection(): Future[Connection] = ??? 
def openStream(c: Connection): Future[InputStream] = ??? 
def processData(stream: InputStream, data: Data): Future[Unit] = ???
def cleanup(stream: InputStream): Unit
```

Now you can write it like

```
   val result: Future[Unit] = openConnection()
      .flatMap(openStream)
      .flatMap { stream => 
         val f = processData(stream, data)
           .onComplete(cleanup(stream)
         f // it's too bad `.onComplete` doesn't return `this` would make things like this look a lot nicer :(
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.map` instead of `.pipe` when working with effects like `Option` or `Either`. There are many good tutorials and examples of effects and how to handle them. I really enjoy Scott Wlashin's approach to teaching. You can find him on youtube [here](https://youtu.be/Nrp_LZ-XGsY).

In your example, you might do something like this:

```
Right(State(conn = None, file = None data = new Data()))
    .map(getConnection)
    .map(openStream)
    .map(...)
```

`.map` runs the function on a `State` if it is a `Right` and ignores it with a `Left`.

On a side note, you should really never use `null` in Scala. Use `None` to represent a missing value.